# Remove "?" from calculation field when exporting

Tags: filemaker

I have numerous calculation fields on my reports, and some have just a "?" instead of the calculated answer, whilst I'm not too bothered by this, it does annoy me when I export my reports and see "?" all over the spreadsheet.

My question is, what is the best way to get around this? Say I wanted to display "0" instead of "?" in my calculation fields, just to tidy up the report when exported. What would be the best way to do this? The calculations are quite complex so I struggled to add in an If statement to display 0 if the result is "?" and I obviously cannot do a find and replace on a calculation field.

Any suggestions/advice welcomed. Thankyou.

Comment: This is my calc If Round(Free Stock / Total Last 7 Days;1)

How would I amend it so that if the result = '?' it instead displays '0'

Comment: I don't know how to amend a calculation I cannot see. And `If Round(Free Stock / Total Last 7 Days;1) ` is not a valid calculation formula. I would guess you get an error because you're trying to divide by zero - so you should test for that first, and only do the actual calculation when it's false.

Comment: Hi Michael,
Thanks for the reply
The calculation is Round(Free Stock / Total Last 7 Days;1) all i want is, if and when the result of that calclation = "?" (regardless of why that may be) I want to return a "0" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the reason why the formula:

```
Round ( Free Stock / Total Last 7 Days ; 1 )
```

returns an error is that the `Total Last 7 Days` field is either empty or evaluates to zero. To prevent such error, you could do:

```
If ( Total Last 7 Days ; Round ( Free Stock / Total Last 7 Days ; 1 ) )
```

which will return an empty result when the divisor is empty or zero.

---

To force a zero result in such case, you could do:

```
If ( Total Last 7 Days ; Round ( Free Stock / Total Last 7 Days ; 1 ) ; 0 )
```

but I don't think it's good practice to output artificial incorrect results.

Comment: Ah brilliant. Exactly what I was looking for, very frustrating that I couldn't work it out I'm disappointed, if its not too much trouble, can you break down for me what is happening so I can understand the logic. Thankyou very much for your help so far :)

Comment: Its a crying shame there is not Private Message system as I have a few more problems very similar to this!

Comment: All it does is test that `Total Last 7 Days` evaluates to `true`. Zero and empty values evaluate to `false`.

Comment: I recommend you join one of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform.